# How to make Django comments use select_related() on "user" field?

Tags: django, performance

I'm using [django comments frameworks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/). All the comments are posted by authenticated users. Near the comment, I'm showing some user profile info using `{{ comment.user.get_profile }}`

```
{# custom comment list templates #}
<dl id="comments">
  {% for comment in comment_list %}
    <dt id="c{{ comment.id }}">
        {{ comment.submit_date }} - {{ comment.user.get_profile.display_name }}
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <p>{{ comment.comment }}</p>
    </dd>
  {% endfor %}
</dl>
```

Problem is that django's comment queries does not use `select_related()` and for 100 comments I get 101 hit on the database.

Is there a way to make django comments framework to select user profile for each comment in one go?

Comment: have you thought about applying some caching to the get_profile

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tested rendering 100 comments for an object with the default `{% get_comment_list %}` tag and django did 200 comment related queries to list the comments + user + profile because...

1. `Comment.__unicode__` actually calls `Comment.user` if a `user_id` exists. +1 query
2. `get_profile` +1 query

Ouch!

I went from 203 queries in ~25ms to 3 in ~2ms.

#### Populate comment_list yourself

I would *highly suggest* building the `comment_list` `QuerySet` yourself using the appropriate `select_related()` calls. If it's used often, create a utility function called from your other views.

```
def get_comments_with_user_and_profile(obj):
    content_type =ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
    return (Comment.objects
        .filter(content_type=content_type, object_pk=obj.id)
        .select_related('user__profile'))
```

#### If you want the entire framework to behave this way... You'll have to monkey patch.

It's not something I would do lightly. There are other ways around this specific problem but you did ask "in one go".

Put this somewhere in your `INSTALLED_APPS` `models.py` files. I actually have a `monkey_patch` app for modifying `django.contrib.auth.models.User.username` lengths and such (which is a last resort unlike here).

```
from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment
from django.contrib.comments.managers import CommentManager

class CommentManager(CommentManager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return (super(CommentManager, self)
            .get_queryset()
            .select_related('user__profile'))
Comment.add_to_class('objects', CommentManager())
```

#### Gotchas with profiles and select_related()

Note that your `UserProfile` class needs a `OneToOneField` to `User` with a `related_name` equal to what you pass to `select_related()`. In my example it's `profile` and you need django 1.2+. I recall stumbling on that before.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile') 
    # example to use User.objects.select_related('profile')
```

Comment: Monkey patch isn't the prettiest solution in the world, but since django has such a "monkey" approach, there is nothing left. Thank you!

Comment: I would prefer explicitly calling the `select_related()` in the views in question. It's your call though of course!

Comment: Monkeypatching is not the answer. The comments app specifically allows you to use your own comments models (see, e.g. ThreadedComments). Seriously all you have to do is create your own fork of ThreadedComments.

Comment: return (Comment.objects
        .filter(content_type=content_type, object_pk=obj.id)
        .select_related('user__profile__DOB')) is selecting all profile table, i wan to select only DOB

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have a setup like so:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='profile')
    ...
```

You can use the following select related: `Comments.objects.select_related('user__pk','user__profile__pk')` and that should do what you want.

You'll have to extend the comments framework. This is fairly straightforward. Basically, create your own comments app. You can look at [django-threadedcomments](http://code.google.com/p/django-threadedcomments/) for inspiration (and, actually, in some ways it's already a better implementation to use anyway).

Here's code you can insert into the django-threaded comments app to make sure it always uses the select related (in models.py):

```
class RelatedCommentManager(CommentManager):
    def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RelatedCommentManager, self).select_related('user__pk','user__profile__pk').filter(*args, **kwargs)

    def exclude(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RelatedCommentManager, self).select_related('user__pk','user__profile__pk').exclude(*args, **kwargs)

    def all(self)
        return super(RelatedCommentManager, self).select_related('user__pk','user__profile__pk').all()
```

and replace

```
    objects = CommentManager()
```

with

```
    objects = RelatedCommentManager()
```

Follow the instructions for integrating threadedcomments into your app.

Then, in the template, I think you'll have to reference `.profile` instead of `.get_profile`.

It *may* be that Django automatically factors this in, so `get_profile` will not generate another db hit so long as `.profile` is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use select_related() in this example, because User is foreign key of profile, not vice versa.
To avoid using cache (which is probably the best option) you could create proxy model for Comment with foreign key to your profile model. then you could write:

```
{{ comment.submit_date }} - {{ comment.user.profile.display_name }}
```

Comment: Actually, I think I can. The only question is how do I do it, since this code is a part of django.

Comment: get_profile is a method, not field or any type of relation that can be get in single query using select_related. to answer question from topic, you can create proxy model  for User/Comment with custom 'objects' manager which will apply select_related to queryset. But this won't solve your problem with getting UserProfile without extra query.

Comment: Actually, the trick is to set up UserProfile with a `OneToOneField` rather than a `ForeignKeyField`. This way, `select_related` will work both ways.