# Django - does model need own table if it inherits solely to change the manager?

Tags: django, django-models, django-inheritance

I've read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887141/how-to-make-django-comments-use-select-related-on-user-field) which deals with the issue of making Django comments use select_related() on “user” field thereby reducing needless sql queries.

The suggestion I like best is to create my own comment model and override the manager currently used.

This is what I have:

```
#models.py
class LightCommentManager(CommentManager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        qs = (super(CommentManager, self).get_query_set().select_related('user'))
        return qs

class LightComment(Comment):
    objects = LightCommentManager()
    class meta:
        managed = False
```

This all works fine but when I syncdb, Django still creates a table for LightComment.  Do I really need to have this table if all I'm changing is the manager, and why does Django create it if managed is set to false?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, your inner class should be called `Meta`, not `meta`.

But rather than `managed = False`, you should be using `proxy = True` to signify that you are creating a proxy model rather than another real model.